# How do I know what language is period-appropriate?

Tags: fiction, resources, language, historical, historical-fiction

I write fiction set in 18th-century England and America. Obviously, they speak English, and equally obviously, they speak it very differently than we do today. For example, I need to know which contractions were common, which were rarely used, and which were not in use yet.

How do I know how to get the language correct and accurate? What kind of resources and reference material will be helpful here?

Comment: You mean you write in the 18th century style? Presumably, then, you have read many 18th century novels. Do you not find the answers to your question in the works your have read? In any case, I am pretty sure this will be considered off topic here.

Comment: I am not sure the full extend of what the English SE does, but asking for words pertaining to a certain time period may or may not be something they can help out with.

Comment: Welcome to Writers.SE! While research questions (or historical questions) are generally off-topic here, I think this question is a valuable one -- figuring out period speech is a common problem for writers. I'm editing slightly to make this more firmly on-topic, and hope you get some great answers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with two basic observations:

- All dialogue is artifice. People in Jane Austen's day did not speak like characters in a Jane Austen novel. Dialogue is not speech. Genuine transcribed speech is painful to read, almost inarticulate at times. Speech is a multimedia phenomenon. Dialogue has to achieve the same effect with just words, and is quite a different beast in consequence.
- All novels are modern. We still read the very best novels of past centuries, but they were written for a different age and a different sensibility. A modern novel, even if set in the past, still needs to be a modern novel and appeal to modern sensibilities. This can include a certain degree of antiquarian interest, which drives a fair part of the historical fiction market, but the antiquarian feeling that such novels provide is, again, an artifice. Real life was not like that.

So, what you want is not dialog based on 18th century speech, both because dialogue is not speech and because what the modern reader of antiquarian tastes wants is something that sounds 18th century to them, which is different from actual 18th century speech (of which, by the way, we have no record or recording).

And happily, that is much easier to research. All you have to do is to read other modern novels set in the 18th century and emulate them.

One of the main issue with the dialogue of historical characters is that the genuine speech of that period would be difficult to follow and would sound very odd to the modern ear. That feeling of oddness, and the difficulty of understanding introduces a kind of oddness to the experience that is not really true to the period because no one in that time would have found any of it odd. You don't want the oddness of the speech to the modern ear to distract the reader and pull them out of the story, so you modernize their speech to a greater or lesser degree. At the same time, you want to avoid any obvious modernism, since that would be equally odd and distracting.

For these reasons, many historical novels seem to be written in what is closer to a timeless universal English, rather than a genuinely period English. And, again, they speak in dialogue, which is not the same thing as speech.

One interesting example, in which essentially modern speech patterns are sprinkled with just enough period vocabulary to be convincing without being offputting, are Patrick O'Brian's Aubrey Maturin series of sea novels, which are set at the beginning of the 19th century. Of course, the closer you get to the modern day, the easier this sort of thing becomes.

Comment: Yes, accuracy will be off-putting, I think, and that's a good point. And of course, all the novels, like today's novels are an imitation of our speech, but not an exact copy. A transcript of someone speaking in an interview today is often peppered with "ums" and "like" that would be torture to read in a novel, unless it's meant to be funny. But novels of the day are worth a read.

Comment: "of which, by the way, we have no record or recording" - if you did want to do this, would old newspapers be a way to get info on this? Presumably they would have generally quoted people with what they actually said?

Answer (score 3):

Just start reading. Type in the words "18th century novels" in ye olde google machine, and you'll get quite a passel of novels: *Moll Flanders* (which I do dearly love), *Robinson Crusoe* and so on. There's also quite a good list at [good reads...](https://www.goodreads.com/list/show/30.Best_Books_of_the_18th_Century) Many of them are available for free online. Once you have your titles, do a search for a PDF of each. Then take notes. If you don't want to read whole novels, scan for dialogue and go from there.

The conversational style of dialogue can be found in these novels and are a great model.

But you could do with reading *Common Sense*, and some founding father literature, including Ben Franklin's stuff. I like his Silence Dogood letters. They have a conversational tone, though they are letters, but if anyone writes a letter in your novel, the habit of weird capitalization was a thing back then...Plus, it's letters to the editor Ben Franklin wrote as a character which is super interesting.

Reading this stuff will help far more than a dictionary of commonly used words would, because you can note tone and structure.